# How to change the format of posts on the hompage?

Tags: themes

I want to edit the format of how posts are display only on the homepage of a Wordpress site but I can't seem to find which template it is that is being used. I'm using the Twentytwelve theme as a base to create a custom theme.

Also when I say the format, I don't mean the post format (ie. bold), I mean the style so changing things around and adding different CSS attributes to elements, that sort of thing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ah! Sorry about this.

It turns out after some further digging and playing around with the theme I figured out that the content.php file is what is being used.

To combat this though I changed the include to content-home and duplicated and renamed the content.php file and now it works. Easy way to alter the design of the homepage.

Answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the number showposts=35 as you want

```
<?php
$page_num = $paged;
if ($pagenum='') $pagenum =1;
query_posts('showposts=35&paged='.$page_num); ?>
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<div class"main">
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<li>posts</li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
        <?php else : ?>

            No Results

        <?php endif; ?>
```

**EDIT:** You can also change number of posts using something like this code in your functions.php First try this one:

```
 if ($query->is_home) {
            $query->set('posts_per_page', 35);
   }
    return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'number_of_posts_on_home');
```